# node js normal callback scenario for blocking code

Tags: node.js, callback

I am getting into callbacks(do not want to use promise and async-await right now) and wrote code in node.js to sum a, b and c where I have created three functions for getting values of a, b and c.

```
// getting value of a
const getA = () => 10

// getting for value b
const getB = () => 20

// This function has to wait for 2 seconds to 
const getC = (callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        callback(30)
    }, 2000);
}

const sum = (a, b, c, callback) => {
    callback(a + b + c)
}

sum(getA(), getB(), getC((c) => c), (sum) => console.log(sum))
```

I want output 60 after waiting for getC() to finish execution, but didn't get any

Answer (score 0):

I really suggest to use promises. I know there are some corner cases, where you can't. Why? Because we used to think in a way that the code is linear, and it is easier to the brain to process.

But for your question I would give a solution.

```js
// getting value of a
const getA = () => 10;

// getting for value b
const getB = () => 20;

// This function has to wait for 2 seconds to
const getC = (callback) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(30);
  }, 2000);
};

getC((val) => console.log(getA() + getB() + val));
```

So you wait until getC has finished, and use the callback to consume the c result.